# Filebeat - multiline: Ingest XML's without line feed at end of file

Tags: xml, logstash, multiline, elastic-stack, filebeat

I want to ingest XML files to the ELK-Stack. I want one event per XML file. These XML files end without line feed, thus filebeat's multiline codec never forwards the last line of the XML to Logstash. Because of this Logstash's XML filter is then not able to parse the XML correctly.

I'm using filebeat 5.2.1.

My XML's look like this (I inserted line feeds (LF) to show):

```
LF
<taskReport>LF
LF
  <toplevelinfo Error="0" Warning="0"/>LF
LF
</taskReport>
```

My filebeat.yml looks like this:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- 
      paths:
        - C:\*.xml
      input_type: log
      document_type: xml
      multiline:
        pattern: '^<taskReport>'
        negate: true
        match: after

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["LS:5044"]
```

Is there an option in filebeat to send this last line within the event?

If I manually add a line feed at the end of the XML logstash can perfectly parse the XML, but this is not an option to me.

Comment: This is something that we are also facing as a team. This is a blocker that prevents filebeat from being used to analyze static files. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/newline-character-required-eof.html